# How can I connect from Windows 10 to the Ubuntu 18.04 VNC server?

Tags: windows-10, vnc, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to use the Ubuntu 18.04 screen sharing feature (Settings – Sharing), but all Windows clients I tried (RealVNC Viewer, TightVNC Viewer, TigerVNC Viewer) have more or less an identical error message: The server works, but the viewer doesn't support any of the server-mandated security types.

I have verified that it works when disabling encryption (`gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false`) but that's not an option for me, I want to connect my Windows 10 Pro to Ubuntu 18.04 with the encryption of course.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug report for this problem :
[Bug #1281250 : VNC accessible from non-linux machines only with encryption disabled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250).

This bug dates from 2014 and has not yet been treated.
The last entry in the bug report dates from 2018-06-17:

> Common guys. This bug is still present in Ubuntu18, and it makes for a
>   truly lousy out-of-box experience.
>
> Just turn encryption off by default.

I don't believe that after four years this bug will be solved any time soon.
The solution might be to use another VNC server than the default one.

See this Ubuntu Community Help Wiki for a list of such servers :
[VNC/Servers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers).

Another alternative is the cross-platform
[NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) :

> Go from your desktop to any NoMachine-enabled computer at the speed of light. Thanks to our NX technology, NoMachine is the fastest and highest quality remote desktop you have ever tried. Get to any computer in the world in just a few clicks! Take what's important where you go and share with who you want! NoMachine is your own personal server, private and secure. Did we say NoMachine is free? No strings attached.

Another solution might be to install on Linux a server for the
Remote Desktop protocol of Windows.
[xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/) might be a solution here :

> Based on the work of FreeRDP and rdesktop, xrdp uses the remote
>   desktop protocol to present a GUI to the user.
>
> The goal of this project is to provide a fully functional Linux
>   terminal server, capable of accepting connections from rdesktop,
>   freerdp, and Microsoft's own terminal server / remote desktop clients.
>
> Unlike Windows NT/2000/2003/2008/2012 server, xrdp will not display a
>   Windows desktop but an X window desktop to the user.

Answer (score -1):

I've never heard of NoMachine so I'm sure that it's Russian spyware.

"Another solution might be to install on Linux a server for the Remote Desktop protocol of Windows. xrdp might be a solution here :"

[https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20Windows,address%20and%20click%20%E2%80%9CConnect%E2%80%9D](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20Windows,address%20and%20click%20%E2%80%9CConnect%E2%80%9D).

If you can get this option to work, please let me know.

A fourth option is to just believe MS when it says that Win10 is effectively Linux :)

Anyway I've tried all of these options now, and they are all based on X, when connecting from Win10 to Ubuntu. So your X configuration will be the make or break point of how well this works.  The only one that I actually got to work to the point where I could remote-control my Ubuntu 20 box was NoMachine, which has a very well-polished shell, it's much like a cross between GoToMeeting and Windows Remote Desktop but it's not nearly as seamless as either one and it still relies on X for the remote display. I know that TightVNC can work very well with vncserver on KDE (we have a client who has set that up for us on a CentOS6 box), but with Ubuntu 20 it's trying to work with GNOME at least by default. Buyer beware.

I'd like to find a working config much more like the TightVNC remote/ vncserver server combo, that really worked fine. But I suspect that KDE on Ubuntu 20 is hopeless. I've been down that road before, it did not work well as Ubuntu is now very closely aligned with GNOME.